# Parsing /proc/pid/smaps output

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have data which is of the form:

```
START
...
... 
END
START
...
...
END
```

I want to do some analysis of the data and therefore would like to extract the lines between `START` and `END`. Now the problem is I want to extract data in chunks. For e.g. Extract data between first pair of `START` and `END` , do analysis then second pair, then third pair. I was exploring sed to do this. How can I use sed ( or any other tool) to accomplish this ?

Comment: you'll get better answers if you edit your post to include some sample data AND your expected output. Sed may be able to help a little bit, but you'll be better off using awk or other programming language. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/START/,/END/{/START/{h;d};H;/END/{g;s/\.\.\./foo/gp};d}' file
START
foo
foo 
END
START
foo
foo
END
```

Or this:

```
awk '/START/{p=1;n++};p{if(n==1)sub(/\.\.\./,"foo");if(n==2)sub(/\.\.\./,"bar");print};/END/{p=0}' file
START
foo
foo 
END
START
bar
bar
END
```